# Nexus 4 not getting 4.3 update

Tags: updates, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4 Device. I had got 4.3 update in System updates about 15 days ago. But I didn't update that time.And now I want to update it so if I go and check for updates, its showing that your system is up to date, while I have 4.2.2 in my phone. Can you please tell me what should I do to get 4.3 update? please guide me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? That might force your device to check for system updates

Comment: As far as I know they're still working the phased rollout. What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the Google Services Framework data. Disconnect from Wifi and mobile data, go to `Settings -> Apps -> All Apps -> Google Services Framework` and tap `Clear data`. After this, restore data connections and go to `Settings -> About phone -> Software Updates` and tap `Check for updates`, and the update should appear. If not, the update is still in rollout for your region.

Answer (score 0):

You can force an actual update check (the "check for update" thing doesn't necessarily do a real check for updates) on some phones by dialing the MMI code *#*#2432546#*#* (the numbers spell "checkin").  Don't push the call button after entering the code, just wait a few seconds.  A notification saying "checkin succeeded" should appear.